# I cant see the alert box while executing this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this code i cant see my alert box when I run this code

```
setInterval(function () {
    location.reload(true);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($("h2").text())
    }) 
}, 6000)
```

The page reloads after 6sec but i do not see my alert box.I would like to understand why, supposing that the tag h2 contains a text... thank you

Comment: you're reloading the page, which means you're KILLING all scripts on the page. That means the doc.ready is destroyed and will never ever execute.

Comment: I'm sorry for those tags D4V1D, but you are not helping me with that. it was a mistake, humans do mistakes! thanks @Marc B, you explained it well; i just succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as it executes location.reload(true), the page reloads and the rest of the script is never executed.

If you want the alert BEFORE the page reloads ([annoying demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/tbeu83qg/)), do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        alert($("h2").text());
        location.reload(true);
    }, 6000);
});
```

If you want the alert AFTER the page loads (i.e. first load and after every reload) ([annoying demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/qs0xtxud/)), do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("h2").text());
    setInterval(function () {
        location.reload(true);
    }, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You'r event has already happened before it's executed. Should use something like this instead...

```js
setInterval(function(){
  (function(){
    alert($("h2").text());
    location.reload(true);       
  })();
}, 6000);
```

Comment: "Your event has already happened before it's executed" is quite confusing. I expect that's why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: Right - what i should of said was the ready event on the document would of already been fired before the first interval.

Comment: well, that's kind of confusing too, because in his code sample the ready event would never have fired at all, because all processing would have stopped at the reload() function call.  Not only would it not have been fired, it never would have been defined in the first place (because the line that defined it would never have executed).